# stop or embed a command prompt window using python

Tags: python-3.x

This code line popups a new command prompt window:

```
os.system("start http-server")
```

How can I stop that window popup or embed that command prompt window into a GUI window?

Comment: Try looking into the subprocess module, specifically `subprocess.Popen` which has a `shell` kwarg you can set to false

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `os.popen()` instead of `os.system`.

`os.popen` is piped open so that you can capture in your python scripts what the program outputs.  `os.system` simply calls the outside program and sends it's contents to stdout. Here is more detail on using [`popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen).